# Groupby and compute ratio in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to compute the conversion rate by age (the conversion column has two values 1 representing conversion success and 0 failure). But I was wondering if there was a more "elegant" way to do this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(30)

### MAKE PSEUDODATA
start_date,end_date = '1/1/2015','12/31/2018'
date_rng = pd.date_range(start= start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
length_of_field = date_rng.shape[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['age'] = np.random.randint(18,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['conversion'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(len(date_rng)))

### ACTUAL CONVERSION CALCULATION 
conversion_by_age = df.groupby(by='age')['conversion'].agg(['count','sum'])
conversion_by_age['rate'] = df.groupby(by='age')['conversion'].sum()/df.groupby(by='age')['conversion'].count()
print(conversion_by_age)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to actually perform the `groupby` many more times once it has been defined. I would use `div` instead of the operator `/` for series/df divisions. I would change the last two lines and obtain the same results:

```
conversion_by_age['rate'] = conversion_by_age['sum'].div(conversion_by_age['count'])
print(conversion_by_age)
```

Another method, taking only 1 line of code, the `rate` column can be calculated within the `groupby` by using a `lambda`:

```
conversion_by_age = df.groupby(by='age').apply(lambda x: x['conversion'].sum() / x['conversion'].count())
```

### Time comparison:

Finally, even though `lambda` is a one liner, it is substantially slower than using `.div()`. These are the times for 1000 runs:

1. Method 1 Time: 0.00981671929359436s +/- 0.0007387502003829031
2. Method 2 Time: 0.015887546062469483 +/- 0.0014185150269994534

Comment: why div instead of the operator /?

Comment: It's a bit more flexible and complete than `/`. From pandas documentation: Equivalent to dataframe / other, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs. With reverse version, rtruediv.

Answer (score 0):

'Named aggregation' dictionaries are [current best-practice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) in pandas (requires pandas.**version**>[0.25.0](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)).

However, you still need to calculate `'rate'` in a second line, as any one-liner would use non-vectorised pandas operations and be much slower.  Overall, I'd suggest:

```
conversion_by_age = df.groupby(by='age').agg(**{'conversion_count':('conversion','count'), 'conversion_sum':('conversion','sum')})
conversion_by_age['rate'] = conversion_by_age['conversion_sum'].div(conversion_by_age['conversion_count'])
```